# How to connect two fock basis with their indexes?

Tags: python, numpy, indexing, scipy

I generate a Fock basis (quantum mechanics) for bossons with a given number of particles `N` and sites `Mtot`, it's just build a set of lists that contains `Mtot` places that must be covered with `N` items (see the code below). Then I build another list of lists with `M` sites (Mtot = 2*M) and with all possible particles/items n = 0,1,2...N. (in my code I am working for N=2, M=2 for simplicity)

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.special import binom

M = 2
Mtot = 2*M
N = 2

def generate(N,nb):
        states = np.zeros((int(binom(nb+N-1, nb)), N), dtype=int)
        states[0, 0]=nb
        ni = 0  # init
        for i in xrange(1, states.shape[0]):
            states[i,:N-1] = states[i-1, :N-1]
            states[i,ni] -= 1
            states[i,ni+1] += 1+states[i-1, N-1]
            if ni >= N-2:
                if np.any(states[i, :N-1]):
                    ni = np.nonzero(states[i, :N-1])[0][-1]
            else:
                ni += 1
        return states.tolist()
basis = generate(Mtot,N)

reduced_basi = [] 
for i in xrange(N+1):
    reduced_basi.append(generate(M,i))
```

Now, the point is that I want to obtain a list that contains the index of the possible states inside `reduced_basi` that can be connected to the other states inside `basis`. For example, using this previous code we will obtain:

```
basis = [[2, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0, 1], [0, 2, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0, 1], [0, 0, 2, 0], [0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 2]]
reduced_basi = [[[0, 0]], [[1, 0], [0, 1]], [[2, 0], [1, 1], [0, 2]]]
```

So with the first item of `reduced_basi` which is `[0, 0]` can be related to `[0, 0, 2, 0]` , `[0, 0, 1, 1]` and `[0, 0, 0, 2]`, then for `[1,0]` it can be related to `[1, 0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0, 1]` ...so that, the list that I want to build must have as first component: `index_list[0] = [7,8,9]` (where 7,8,9 are the corresponding index of `basis` states following the same order) and the second: `index_list[1] = [2,3]` . At the end it must be done sistematically and as result I have to obtain the following list for this particular case (I have computed it by hand):

```
index_list = [[7,8,9],[2,3],[5,6],[0],[1],[4]]
```

Any idea how can be implemented this?

Comment: So you basically want the indices that share the same start sequence?

Comment: yes, exactly this

Comment: Why is `reduce_basi` packed hierarchically? Do you want to maintain that?

Comment: ah well, in fact is not needed packed it hierarchically. So that, it can be discarted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define a function:

```
def samestart(pattern,sequence):
    for i,d in enumerate(pattern):
        if d != sequence[i]:
            return False
    return True
```

You can in fact rewrite it as:

```
def samestart(pattern,sequence):
    return all(x == y for x,y in zip(pattern,sequence))
```

Next you can simply use list comprehension:

```
[[i for i,sequence in enumerate(basis) if samestart(pattern,sequence)] for patterns in reduced_basi for pattern in patterns]
```

In `python` this produces:

```
$ python3
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 17 2016, 17:05:23) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> def samestart(pattern,sequence):
...     for i,d in enumerate(pattern):
...         if d != sequence[i]:
...             return False
...     return True
... 
>>> basis = [[2, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0, 1], [0, 2, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0, 1], [0, 0, 2, 0], [0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 2]]
>>> reduced_basi = [[[0, 0]], [[1, 0], [0, 1]], [[2, 0], [1, 1], [0, 2]]]
>>> [[i for i,sequence in enumerate(basis) if samestart(pattern,sequence)] for patterns in reduced_basi for pattern in patterns]
[[7, 8, 9], [2, 3], [5, 6], [0], [1], [4]]
```

It is not terrible efficient: one can definitely use hashing here to boost performance.

---

If **you can make the assumption** that all "patterns" have length two, you can simply derive this and construct a dictionary. For instance:

```
result = {}
for idx,base in enumerate(basis):
    pattern = tuple(base[0:2])
    patlist = result.get(pattern)
    if patlist is not None:
        patlist.append(idx)
    else:
        result[pattern] = [idx]
```

This will produce a dictionary `result`:

```
>>> result
{(0, 1): [5, 6], (2, 0): [0], (0, 0): [7, 8, 9], (1, 0): [2, 3], (1, 1): [1], (0, 2): [4]}
```